# Display Country's name in Textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, prompt

Goal:
Display the name of countries in a list based on selection.
For instance, if I select Australia and France, the country's name should display in the textbox.
If I select (Select All), all the country's name shall be printed in the textbox.

Problem:
I do not know how to do it. I can retrieve one country but not many countries.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a comma-delimited string of selected parameters in a textbox, you would use an expression like:

```
=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Label, ", ")
```

Since the parameter is multi-value its `Label` property will be an array, so `Join` takes the array and turns it back into a single string.